# Inequality in a triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

Let $O$ be the circumcenter and $H$ the orthocenter in a triangle with sides $a, b, c$. Is it true that $$aOA^2+bOB^2+cOC^2 \ge aHA^2 + bHB^2 + cHC^2$$ or equivalently
$$(a+b+c)R^2 \ge aHA^2 + bHB^2 + cHC^2$$ where $R$ is the circumradius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true!

a counter example is $  a=5,b=6,c=8$, but for some $a,b,c$  satisfy it.

Edit: 
This is the case that $H$ is inside the circle.

[image]

it is trivial that $AH$ //  $EC$,$\angle EAC=\angle EBC= \dfrac{\pi}{2}-\angle BEC =\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\angle BAC =\angle ACF \implies AE$ // $HC \implies AH=EC$

it is trivial that $EC^2=BE^2-BC^2=4R^2-a^2=AH^2$

Comment: Can you give $R$ and $HA, HB, HC$ in this triangle to show that this really is a counterexample? Thank you.

Comment: $R$ you can calculate. $HA^2=4R^2-a^2$

Comment: Yes, for $R$ we can use $R=abc/4F$, with $F$ the area. But the formula you give for $HA$ is not known to me. Can you please prove it?